# How to use Background worker in asp.net ?is there any samples in asp.net because Do work event is not firing

Tags: asp.net

In my application i have to bind huge amount of data to datagridview.still data bind progress bar should be used to show the progress .i have create an instance of background worker and added events Do work and Run worker completed but both are not firing is any properties should be set to fire the events in asp.netif i use RunWorkerAsync following error occured

Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the background process in asp.net you can use threads and thread process for this..